# Paysafe 3D Secure 2 api issue

Tags: .net, paysafe

I'm integrating my site with 3D Secure 2 and I don't know how to get the information I need to execute JavaScript SDK Start Function

```
paysafe.threedsecure.start("my Base64 encoded single-use API key", {
environment: "TEST",
accountId: "Preferred account ID",
card: {
    cardBin: "The card BIN"
}
```

}, function (deviceFingerprintingId, error) {...});

Also testing the API functions on backoffice services implementations using
`https://api.test.paysafe.com/threedsecure/v2/accounts/{{account_id}}/authentications` is getting me this response:

```
{
"liveMode": true,
"error": {
    "code": "5269",
    "message": "Merchant configuration not found",
    "details": [
        "No merchant configuration with merchant account id 1001290230 found."
    ]
}
```

}

Do I need to specify on request something that is test mode or something? 
how to work correctly with this new improvements?

PS: I'm using test mode and my merchant id is in my test account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Is your account enabled for 3DS2?
My older account was not, so I had to ask the support team to do so.

Comment: You are totally right, support does not complete the merchant account migration to 3Ds version 2 on that account. Thank you!